# Returning plain text or other arbitary file in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, http, web-applications

If I were to respond to an http request with a plain text in PHP, I would do something like:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo "This is plain text";
?>
```

How would I do the equivalent in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you only want to return plain text like that I would use an ashx file (Generic Handler in VS). Then just add the text you want to return in the ProcessRequest method.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("This is plain text");
    }
```

This removes the added overhead of a normal aspx page.

Answer (score 19):

You should use Response property of Page class:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
Response.Write("This is plain text");
Response.End();
```

Comment: Technically you don't need the Response.Flush() because that is included in the Response.End() method.

Answer (score 4):

Example in C# (for VB.NET just remove the end `;`):

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("This is plain text");
```

You may want to call `Response.Clear` beforehand in order to ensure there are no headers or content in the buffer already.

Comment: Okay. So I would just have an empty .aspx page, and put this in the code-behind?

Comment: @Jo-Herman Haugholt - pretty much, though this could also be in a code block (`<%%>`) on the aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("This is plain text");
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you migrate to asp net core / blazor:

```
            string str = "text response";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```