# How to get Response.Write() result in string using method of return type void in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a `webservice asmx` written for `Android and ios`, communicate well with both of them, Methods that i used to return values in `json` format and example method is :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Get_Rest_Distance(double startlat,double endlat,double startlng, double endlng)
{
     double dist= GetDistance(startlat, endlat, startlng, endlng);
     JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dist));
}
```

the line: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dist));`

is used to give data to api call from android and ios,

Now want to call this method from my `aspx` page `(Code Behind)` and you noticed that return type of my function is `void`

I added reference of my `webserivice` and wrote some lines like:

```
localhost.RestData obj = new localhost.RestData();
 string testdata=  obj.Get_Rest_Distance(33.200526, 34.027379, -87.5441, -88.167831);
```

but getting error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'
```

As i mentioned method is of return type `void` and now i want to get that data which `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dist));` statement returns or write.

**Note:**
Cannot use `return` in methods as service is live and both versions android and ios are working in production environment.

Please feel free to ask any question, i will provide more code if needed.

Comment: as per your error suggests there is no return type(void) for web service. But you are trying to access a string from your web service method in  "string testdata=  obj.Get_Rest_Distance(33.200526, 34.027379, -87.5441, -88.167831); " code

Comment: actually i want to get values that HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dist)); 
returns...

Comment: not sure it can help you or not. What i will suggest you to create an ashx file (Generic Handler in VS) and call your service from there and you can use this ashx inside your aspx. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078152/returning-plain-text-or-other-arbitary-file-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use Out Parameter which is something like this :

```
static void OutParameter(out int tmp)
    {
        ShowValue("OutParameter (pre): ");
        tmp = 10;
        ShowValue("OutParameter (post): ");
    }
```

Comment: but i am not permitted to change code in service,  i need to access it in aspx page only